Is the husband sinful if his wife refuses to wear hijab?
Salam,
The title sums up 70% of the question.
The scenario is, say a woman refuses to wear hijab because she does not want to wear it(she dresses modestly for the rest of clothing), that is there is no health hazard or other problems. Her husband talks to her, tries to change her mind in all possible ways but she is bent on not wearing it.
In such a scenario will the husband accountable for wife's sin? Is it permissible to marry a woman who does not wear hijab? If such a case occurs after marriage should the husband divorce his wife?
I have done some research but I want a comprehensive, well sourced and compiled opinion from more knowledgeable persons on here.
Thank you

Wearing hijab is a religious obligation and what the wife wants is irrelevant. She has to wear hijab no matter what.

وما كان لمؤمن ولا مؤمنة إذا قضى الله ورسوله أمرا أن يكون لهم الخيرة من أمرهم ومن يعص الله ورسوله فقد ضل ضلالا مبينا
It is not for a believing man or a believing woman, when Allah and His Messenger have decided a matter, that they should [thereafter] have any choice about their affair. And whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger has certainly strayed into clear error.
— Quran 33:36

The husband must educate the wife about this matter, after that the wife's continued abstinence can be due to one of the following reasons:

She refuses, denying the obligation or claiming that she can do as she pleases. This is Kufr and she is an apostate. Initiating marriage is not permitted with an apostate. If she is already married then the marriage is rendered void. See Does the marriage of a man who leaves Islam remain valid?

She acknowledges that wearing Hijab is essential, but she fails to observe it because of negligence or because of failing to control temptations. In this case she is merely a sinner. Marriage to a sinner can be initiated and can be retained if it has already occurred. However it is obviously better to marry a righteous woman and it is acceptable to divorce a woman because of this reason.


The rest of this answer assumes the second case.
The husband will be blameworthy if he fails to prevent his wife from sinning to the best of his ability. People can be held accountable by Allah if they observe a sin occurring in their midst and do not attempt to stop it:

واتقوا فتنة لا تصيبن الذين ظلموا منكم خاصة واعلموا أن الله شديد العقاب
And fear a trial which will not strike those who have wronged among you exclusively, and know that Allah is severe in penalty.
— Quran 8:25


ما من قوم يعمل فيهم بالمعاصي ثم يقدرون على أن يغيروا ثم لا يغيروا إلا يوشك أن يعمهم الله منه بعقاب
If acts of disobedience are done among any people and other people do not change them though the are able to do so, Allah will soon punish them all.
— Abu Dawud

The above texts are general and applicable to the husband as well. Actually the husband is a guardian over his wife and hence even more worthy of being accountable:

يا أيها الذين آمنوا قوا أنفسكم وأهليكم نارا وقودها الناس والحجارة
O you who have believed, protect yourselves and your families from a Fire whose fuel is people and stones
— Quran 66:6 


الرجال قوامون على النساء
Men are in charge of women
— Quran 4:34


كلكم راع فمسئول عن رعيته ... والرجل راع على أهل بيته وهو مسئول عنهم
Everyone of you is a guardian and is responsible for his charges ... a man is a guardian of his family and is responsible for them
— Bukhari

The first step to preventing sin is to inform and advise the person in a kind manner. From the question it is apparent that the husband has already tried this and it was not effective. However, the husband's responsibility does not end there rather he must go beyond this and even force the wife with harsh measures if necessary, as the hadith says:

من رأى منكم منكرا فليغيره بيده فإن لم يستطع فبلسانه فإن لم يستطع فبقلبه وذلك أضعف الإيمان
Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand; if he cannot, then (disapprove of it) with his tongue; and if he cannot, then (hate it) with his heart and that is the weakest of faith.
— Muslim

Being the wife's guardian the husband has the legal ability to discipline her in other ways when needed:

واللاتي تخافون نشوزهن فعظوهن واهجروهن في المضاجع واضربوهن فإن أطعنكم فلا تبغوا عليهن سبيلا
But those [wives] from whom you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist], forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you [once more], seek no means against them.
— Quran 4:34


‏ فإن فعلن فاهجروهن في المضاجع واضربوهن ضربا غير مبرح فإن أطعنكم فلا تبغوا عليهن سبيلا
If they do that, then forsake them in their beds and hit them, but without causing injury or leaving a mark. If they obey you, then do not seek means of annoyance against them.
— Ibn Majah


قال قلت يا رسول الله ما حق زوجة أحدنا عليه قال أن تطعمها إذا طعمت وتكسوها إذا اكتسيت - أو اكتسبت - ولا تضرب الوجه ولا تقبح ولا تهجر إلا في البيت
Mu'awiyah asked: O Messenger of Allah, what is the right of the wife of one of us over him? He replied: That you should give her food when you eat, clothe her when you clothe yourself, do not strike her on the face, do not revile her or separate yourself from her except in the house.
— Abu Dawud

A husband can use the following measures:

scolding
refusing to talk to her, speaking to her in a harsh tone, refusing intimacy when she desires it, granting her turn to another wife
beating her
withholding her maintenance and other facilities which the husband provides her
confining her to the house and refusing to let her leave it without wearing hijab

Some scholars have stated that if he is powerless to stop her then it is recommended to divorce her, see Kashshaaf al-Qinaa’.

Ref:

وأما ضرب الزوجة فجائز  ... ومنه ما إذا كشفت وجهها لغير محرم
As for hitting a wife then the matters in which it is permissible includes ... if she uncovers her face in front of a non-mahram
— Al-Bahr ar-Raiq


يعزر المولى عبده والزوج زوجته ... كشفت وجهها لغير محرم
A master can carry out Taz'eer on his slave and a husband on his wife for ... uncovering her face in front of a non-mahram
— Durr al-Mukhtaar


مسائل الإجماع والاتفاق في باب ... وعلى أن له منعها من الخروج
The matters of consensus and agreement in this topic are ... it is the right of the husband to forbid his wife from going out of the house
— Mizan al-Kubra


You can't be seriously saying a man should beat his wife if she does not wear a hijab. How can you possibly suggest this in our modern world on a public forum such as this.

@Jonathan, the answer is well-supported and shows objective scholarly views, which is what OP asked for. We may consider this inappropriate in our modern view and I see a certain contradiction the SE Code of Conduct. Still we have to admit that no matter what standards apply today in “modern” society, it is simply hypocritical/false to deny that this is part of the religious teaching.  I see no encouragement or promotion of wife-beating here, this is just an objective response that you may or may not like. If we blindly apply the Code of Conduct, this will lead to censorship and suppression.
